# Photo Competition 2021-05-03: Typography

Tags: photo-competition

### Theme: Typography

A photo with a focus on typography. Letters, numbers, words and so on. The shapes of them, the layout or where they're placed. Address numbers on buildings are sometimes quite interesting. Writing on roads, signs and so on.

I imagine the focus being on the presentation of the words, rather than the meaning of them but I can see that latter working too.

This theme was suggested by [Vian Esterhuizen](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4124/vian-esterhuizen).

#### Voting Rules

- View the submissions [sorted by active](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/124613/photo-competition-2021-05-03-typography?answertab=active#tab-top) to give every submitter a fair chance
- Vote up as many images as you like
- Please, **up votes only!** Do NOT vote down your competitors! If you don't like an image, don't vote
- **Voting closes on May 10, 2021 at 12:01 AM UTC** (00:01 UTC if you prefer a 24-hour time). The winner will be chosen based on votes at that time.

#### Submission Rules

1. One photo submission per answer. Up to three (3) entries allowed.
2. Post only photos taken by yourself or the person with you.
3. **All entries should include:**

   - a **title** for the photo
   - a **location and date**, if known
   - **camera, lens, and exposure settings**, if known
   - any other explanatory notes, comments, etc., that you want to include (completely optional)
4. The submitted image must conform to this site's content license, Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 ([CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).
5. Do not use this as a forum for photo critique. Use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=photo.stackexchange.com) instead, or [ask a new question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about your image.

---

#### Next Contest

Suggest a theme by writing a new answer at the [Photo of the Week Theme Ideas](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1740/) thread. Please make sure to check the [PotW theme ideas Archive](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1741/) first, to make sure you aren't recycling a theme.

The highest-voted theme will be the next theme.

Good luck!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## **Confidential**

Manila, 2019

iPhone 8 + macro attachment, desaturated with minor exposure adjustments[image]

Answer (score 18):

### [Numbers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M3f-JwOGO1A)

[image: 1,2,3]

At [MONA](https://mona.net.au/) (Museum of Old and New Art), Hobart, Australia.

September 2013

Canon EOS 5D III, EF24-105 f/4L @ 65 mm f/5.6, 1/13 s, ISO 3200.

Answer (score 18):

## Movable Type

Colonial Williamsburg, 2018-11-21

Sony a7R II, Minolta MD 50/1.4(?), f/1.4(?) @ 1/3s

[image: movable type]

Answer (score 16):

## Surviving the Flames

[image: A book that survived a house fire]

This book survived a house fire. It was rescued from the flames when the bookshelf it was on collapsed, throwing it into the fireplace and into the path of the water pouring in from the fire fighter's hoses. This photo was taken two days later as the book dried in the sunlight streaming in through the collapsed roof.

Answer (score 11):

### Laphroaig

[image]

Oulu, Finland, 2021-03-30.

Fujica ST801 - EBC Fujinon 55mm f/1.8 with a short macro extension tube - Ilford Ortho+ 80

Aperture f/1.8. Shutter speed either 1/4 or 1/8. Testing the lens with the macro tube.

Answer (score 11):

## Disinterest

September 2020, on the Vienna Underground (["U-Bahn"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vienna_U-Bahn))

Minolta XG-1 on Kodak T-Max 400, Soligor Macro<sup>*</sup> @ 1/1000s

[image: Photo "Disinterest" by Alexander Leithner]

This leaflet reads "Because Racism is everyday life for far too many in Vienna" and was part of the election campaign of a new communist/leftist party ("LINKS", which translates to "LEFT") running for mayor, city council and state government in [2020's Vienna State Election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_Viennese_state_election). Seeing this flyer end up on the floor of a mass transit network station made me wonder whether such issues are addressed often and thoroughly enough in Europe.

---

<sup>*</sup> Sadly, neither I nor the previous owner of the camera and lens recall what model it is.

Answer (score 10):

### Footnotes in Footnotes in Footnotes

Germany, 2021-04-26, Sony DSC-R1 30.2mm/7.1 @ 1/1000s (flash)

Critical editions summarise several different text versions in a manner where one can actually cite the exact page and wording from any of the covered variants.  This critical apparatus contains a canonical version with its original author footnotes, a layer of footnotes representing variant versions, and another layer of footnotes from the current editor.

[image: Critical edition typesetting]

Answer (score 10):

## In need of protection

February 2021, near the famous Prater amusement park in Vienna, Austria (specifically right in front of the ["Republik Kugelmugel"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kugelmugel))

Minolta XG-1 on Kodak UltraMax 400, Soligor Macro<sup>*</sup> @ 1/250s, if I recall correctly

[image: Photo "In need of protection" by Alexander Leithner]

This sign is pretty close the the official street signs of the City of Vienna: it uses the same font, colour and layout ("2.," denotes the district, in this case the second district, Leopoldstadt) but is fictitious as is the whole Republic of Kugelmugel. It reads "Anti-Fascism Square" in German which is especially ironic as Austria's history includes episodes of Fascism where razor wire was among the utilities of first choice. Thus, seeing something dedicated to Anti-Fascism behind razor wire made me take this photo and think about this for a while.

---

<sup>*</sup> Sadly, neither I nor the previous owner of the camera and lens recall what model it is.

Answer (score 9):

### Hope

Los Gatos, CA, April 25th 2021

Nikon D500 with Nikkor 18-140

f/18, 1/10, ISO-20000

Lit using iphone flash and moon used as a backlight behind bottlecap. The image displays differently on different screens so if you can't read the text it says "Democracy Dies in Darkness" and "The Washington Post"

[image]

Answer (score 9):

## Traditional Pharmacy

Shirakawa, Japan, 08/25/2017

EOS 6D, 35mm@EF24-105 f/4L, 1/125, f/5.6, 3200

[image: Traditional Pharmacy]

Answer (score 9):

### As a Science Student - 2013

[image]

This was taken by a phone, a very low resolution phone. I was quite forcing myself to study those days and was feeling depressed. I found this quote motivating.

Answer (score 7):

## Many Leather Bound Books

Trinity College, May 2019

Galaxy s8

[image: Many Leather Bound Books]

Answer (score 6):

### THANK U ❤︎ DR. FAUCI

San Francisco, June 27th 2020

Canon Rebel T1I & Tamron 70-300 Macro

f/10, 1/160, ISO-200

[image]

Answer (score 6):

### Words fail to convey the real message

Picture taken in Bangkok's Safari World on April 13th 2021. Photo taken with my Sony RX10M3 at f/3.2, shutter time 1/125s at 18.92mm and ISO320.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

## Conquistadores

I have some phrases for handwrite practicing, one of which being "Conquistadores" as it has a nice flow of the letters.  Then the Sun came in and the shadow of the pen caught my eye and I tried to capture it with my iPhone 8.

[image: writing in sun light]

Comment: Wouldn't that be calligraphy?

Comment: @user98068 Yep, but it's much closer to typography than many of the graphical rubbish captured on some of the other photos.

Answer (score 5):

### In the Beginning Was the Word

Germany, 2021-04-26, Sony DSC-R1 22.2mm/13.0 @ 1/1000s (flash)

Latin/Greek New Testament critical edition, John 1
[image: John 1]

Answer (score 4):

### Typographer's favourite shirt

Prague, April 29th, 2021

[image]

- LG G8s ThinQ (LM-G810)
- ISO 150, F1.8, 1/50
- Focal length 4.26mm (35mm equiv 26mm)

Shirt courtesy of Coton Doux, France.

Answer (score 3):

### Roadside beer can art

Some interesting texts at this roadside beer can art exposition / sale. While can't read most of them, the message on the light post has some English text on it:

> Some of the things you have I my lack. And some of the things that you lack, I might have.

Picture taken through a car window somewhere in Khon Kaen, Thailand on the 28th of March.  Photo taken with my Sony RX10M3 at f/3.5, shutter time 1/320s at 31.33mm and ISO100. The typography is best enjoyed after clicking on the picture to get a higher resolution version.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

**Modern Times**

October 16 2020

iPhone SE

Comment: lol. Dropcap and all.\

Answer (score 2):

### Selling Stolen Stuff

Gas Station in Middle of Nowhere in Southern California, February 14th 2021

Canon Rebel T1I & Tamron 70-300 Macro

f/14, 1/800, ISO-1600

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### One more day to go !!

An interesting drawing on my breakfast delivery on the last full day of quarantine. Picture taken on March 26th at the Pullman Alternative State Quarantine facility in Bangkok.

Photo taken with my Sony RX10M3 at f/2.4, shutter time 1/400s at 8.8mm and ISO100.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## Inscription on the Basin of the [Forum Baths](https://sites.google.com/site/ad79eruption/pompeii/public-buildings/forum-baths)

Pompeii, Italy, 10/05/2016

EOS 6D, 20mm@EF16-35mm f/4L, 1/30, f/8, 1600

"Cold water was piped into the basin at the centre of the photograph, thus enabling bathers to cool off when they wanted." - [Work and Play in Everyday Pompeii Gallery](https://www.bbc.co.uk/history/ancient/romans/daily_life_gallery_06.shtml)

"The apse at its southern end contains a labrum or marble basin (pictured right and below) provided, according to the inscription, by the duoviri Cn. Melissaeius Aper and M. Staius Rufus for the not insubstantial sum of 5,250 sesterces." - [Forum Baths](https://sites.google.com/site/ad79eruption/pompeii/public-buildings/forum-baths)

[image: ForumBathBasin]

Answer (score 2):

Messages written in UV pen.

Taken 30/10/2020 @ Compton Verney, UK.
OM-D E-10 Mk III
f/4.5, 1/13 @ 53mm with the 40-150 "kit" lens
ISO 1250

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Door Bell

For a small fee, you can climb the narrow stairs to the top of the tallest church in the world. In the evening, the doors get closed and locked. This bell is intended for those unfortunate visitors who find themselves trapped in the upper half of the church tower.

Ulm Minster, Ulm, Germany. December 2019. Huawei Honor 10 Lite.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### American Ink

Some beautiful labels on several ink bottles by American companies, as can be seen in [Gallen-Kallela](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akseli_Gallen-Kallela)'s atelier in Tarvaspää, Espoo, Finland.

[image]

*30|08|2020*
Olympus OM-D E-M10 Mk II
f1.8 | 1/50s | ISO 640 | 45mm

Answer (score 2):

## Where studying meets boredom

France, 2012-05-20, HTC Desire HD

This was by far the worst course I ever studied. It was very difficult to concentrate so I'd rather try to write as well as possible or take pictures than really study...

[image]